# MS word font falls to TimesNewRoman when going across Hebrew

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, language, hebrew

Usually, I deal with MS Word in 3 languages (English, Hebrew, Arabic), It keep falls Back to Font: TimesNewRoman every time I write, or even toggle over the languages.
This problem actually occurs when I'm writing with font that isn't support one of the other languages (Hebrew isn't supported by Traditional Arabic font (TA for short)). The problem occurs exactly when going across Hebrew. (Which isn't supported by TA) so the font changes to TimeNewRoman and stays, even when changing the language back to Arabic.

How can I make the "non-supported language by current font" being written with Calibri instead of TimeNewRoman, or keeping the font came back to my current font instead of failing to TimeNewRoman.

I have been tried some ways with no benefit:

- changing the fonts for Styles.
- changing the default font.
- changing set of The Theme's font.[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJDNy.png)
- Creating and Applying all those changes to the Normal.dotm Template instead of just current document.

Extra info:
This problem occurs when using two complex languages, I was hop that I can chose a font for each language instead of just choosing a font for the Complex languages.

Answer (score 0):

As a Temporary Solution, I Created Macros so I can have the desired font semi-automatically

```
    Sub Arabic()
    Selection.Font.Name = "Traditional Arabic"
End Sub
Sub Hebrew()
    Selection.Font.Name = "David"
End Sub
Sub English()
    Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
End Sub
```

And then defining a shortcut icon & shortcut key for each font:

1. Display the Word Options
2. At the left side of the dialog box, click Customize Ribbon
3. Click Customize Keyboard
4. Select the Macros category
5. Select the macro you want assigned to a shortcut key and assign..
6. I chose Ctrl+Alt+Q for English, Ctrl+Alt+W for Hebrew, Ctrl+Alt+E for Arabic.

And by the way, I am already assigned the ctrl+1 to english, ctrl+2 Hebrew, ctrl+3 arabic. using Autohotkey and this code:

```
^1::SetInputLang(0x0409) ; English (USA)
^2::SetInputLang(0x040d) ; Hebrew
^3::SetInputLang(0x0401) ; arabic saudi arabia

SetInputLang(Lang)
{
    WinExist("A")
    ControlGetFocus, CtrlInFocus
    PostMessage, 0x50, 0, % Lang, %CtrlInFocus%
}
```

Hope That's Helpful,
Bm3